# Highchart bubble chart shows empty chart

Tags: highcharts

I have this simple bubble chart https://jsfiddle.net/zengoric/4qyqokgj/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bubble',
  },
  series: [{
    "name": "First data set",
    "data": [{     
      "x": 0,      
      "y": 2,      
      "z": 4.61,      
    }],
    "sizeByAbsoluteValue": true,   
  }, {
    "name": "Second data set",
    "data": [{      
      "x": -1,     
      "y": -3,      
      "z": 4.6,      
    }],
    "sizeByAbsoluteValue": true
  }]
});
```

but it display nothing. Something is wrong with data or it's a bug in highcharts library?

Comment: Remove the both `"sizeByAbsoluteValue": true`

Comment: I need these options, so i can't remove them(

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize `zMin` or/and `zMax` properties to make bubbles visible.

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gs2dr565/

Bubbles are too small to be drawn in the example that you provided.

---

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.zMin
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.zMax

Comment: Actually this was a bug in highcharts library and it already has been fixed https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8092
But thanks for your reply anyway)